# Dynamic UITableViewCell height causing layout issues

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell set up to display a users timeline in my app with a custom cell.

As you would expect, the cell height should adjust based on the length of the tweet. In my custom Tweet class, I have added a property called cellHeight and set it like so when I load my data:

```
/******************************************************/
// Cell Height
/******************************************************/

 float cellHeight = ceilf([self textViewHeightForText:tweetFinalText andWidth:222]);

 float topPadding = 10.0f;
 float bottomPadding = 10.0f;
 float labelHeight = 21.0f;

 float final_height = cellHeight + topPadding + labelHeight + bottomPadding;

 aTweet.cellHeight = final_height;

 [temp insertObject:aTweet atIndex:i];
```

Here is my heightForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Tweet *aTweet = [self.userTweetsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return aTweet.cellHeight;

}
```

This is all pretty simple and straight forward. It actually works perfectly for sizing the cell, but now my UILabel that stores the username gets moved up or down. Here are some pictures to illustrate this:

[image: First Example]

[image: Second Example]

As you can see ONLY the username label gets thrown off. If I change heightForRow to lets say just 100, everything goes back to normal. It is also worth noting that the tweet text is always where it needs to be.

I am not using auto layout, and I am not setting the labels location/frame programmatically (it is done in the storyboard prototype cell). When I set the code programmatically in cellForRowAtIndexPath, nothing happens.

If I enable auto layout the cells looks great, but the rest of my app gets majorly jumbled because it was entirely built with auto layout. I do not wish to use auto layout for this project

Any idea as to why it is having this behavior? Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if there is any code I can post that might help, Thanks!

Comment: use an uitextview, uilabels aling text vertical in the middle

Comment: you need to 'glue' the `UILabel` to the top of the cell, the `AutoResizeMask` can give you an easy solution for it, but the `AutoLayout` does perfectly support to do such a thing.

Comment: I am actually using a 3rd party class called STTweetLabel which is a UILabel. It allows auto detection of hashtags and @usernames. With that being said I fixed the issue. I guess some connections were messed up because once I deleted the label and reconnected the outlet, everything works perfectly. Easy fix for a random glitch I guess